# Is there any way to copy few characters to clipboard in textpad?

Tags: search, replace

I'm trying to replace a few character word in one place with the word searched in another. I.e

```
VARIABLE INT005 SOME TEXT BETWEEN NAME=INT020;
```

I want the program To copy whats after VARIABLE (INT005 in this case) and paste it after NAME=(here should be again INT005 replaced into the place of INT020)

Answer (score 0):

A regex replacement should work here.  Assuming you are only looking to make these replacements on a single line, you may try the following find and replace:

```
Find:    \bVARIABLE (\S+)(.*?)\bNAME=\S+;
Replace: VARIABLE $1$2NAME=$1
```

### Demo

**Edit:**

If your text could span multiple lines, then *either* turn on "dot all" mode from Textpad (not sure where you would do that), or use this find version:

```
\bVARIABLE (\S+)([\s\S]*?)\bNAME=\S+;
```